# Dart Analysis problems not shown in editor in Android Studio Bumblebee

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

After upgrading Android Studio to v2022.1.1 (Bumblebee) Dart Analysis problems shown in the corresponding tab are not shown within the editor itself.

Typos on the other hand are shown as one can see in the attached screenshot.

Flutter doctor shows no issues and restarting Android Studio doesn't help either. I haven't found any other developers reporting the same issue so I assume it's upon me, but I have no clue what I might have changed to cause this behaviour.

[image: Android Studio].

Answer (score 2):

This answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223418/1998851. I'm not sure how I broke things, but going to Dart Analysis -> Dart Analysis Server Settings -> Scope Analysis to current package, fixed things